# Balancing the reaction of nitric acid with zinc using oxidation number method

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, stoichiometry

In a previous question, there was confusion relating to what this "oxidation number method" is. So I will illustrate that before my question.

> 1. Write the skeleton equation representing chemical change.
> 2. Assign oxidation numbers to the atoms in the equation and then write separate equations for atoms undergoing oxidation and reduction.
> 3. Find the change in oxidation number in each equation. Make the change in both equations by multiplying with suitable integers. Add both the equations.
> 4. Complete the balancing by inspection. First balance those that have undergone change in ON and then other atoms except H and O. Finally, balance the Hs, the Os will be automatically balanced.
>
> Example:
>   $$\ce{Cu  + HNO3 -> Cu(NO3)2 + NO2 }$$
>   $$\ce{Cu^0 -> Cu^{+II}(NO3)2} \tag{1}$$
>   $$\ce{HN^{+V}O3 -> N^{+IV}O2} \tag{2} $$
>
> To make increase and decrease in ON equal, equation 2 is multiplied by $2$. Adding we get,
>
> $$\ce{Cu + 2 HNO3 -> Cu(NO3)2 + 2NO2 + H2O} \implies \ce{Cu + 4 HNO3 -> Cu(NO3)2 + 2NO2 + 2H2O}$$

## Question:

Balance $\ce{Zn + HNO3 -> Zn(NO3)2 + H2O + N2O}$

I am trying to use oxidation number method but unable to reach the right answer.

The half equations are:

$\ce{Zn -> Zn^2+(NO3)2 \tag{1}}$

$\ce{2HN^{+V}O3 -> N^{+I}2O \tag{2}}$

Thus we should multiply the first equation by 2 and then add.

$\ce{2Zn + 2HNO3 -> N2O + 2Zn(NO3)2}$

Then I tried balancing the nitrogens by adding one 2HNO3s to LHS but after that the oxygens ust won't balance!

How do I go about balancing this then?

Comment: First, I'd write all half-equations with ionic compounds in ionic form, even if asked otherwise. Second, if an atom costs 10 bucks, then two atoms cost 20; now replace bucks with electrons. Third, how would you go about finding the formula of zinc nitrate, were it not given to you in the problem statement?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate-
Let the final balanced equation be $\ce{yZn + 2xHNO3-> yZn(NO3)2 +xH2O +zN2O}$

Now For balancing nitrogen we must have $2x=2y+2z$ and for balancing oxygen atoms we should have $6x=6y+x+z$ Now we get an equation $x=5z$. Put $z=1$ you get $x=5$ and $y=4$.

Hence the balanced equation is:

$$\ce{4Zn + 10HNO3 ->  4Zn(NO3)2 + 5H2O + N2O}$$